# Load html (getText) based on global tabs

Tags: plone

I am trying to load different html pages based on each global tab (each tab would load a different html page) using getText. Does anyone know the code to specify a certain tab for each different piece of text? The code below loads the same text into all the tabs:

```
<div class="col_3" metal:define-macro="highlights" i18n:domain="plone">
<h2>Highlights</h2>
<p> 
<tal:block tal:condition= "exists:here/graduate-study/highlghts-grad"
tal:replace="structure here/graduate-study/highlghts-grad/getText">Footer content here</tal:block>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col_3" metal:define-macro="highlights" i18n:domain="plone">
<h2>Highlights</h2>
<p> 
<tal:block tal:condition= "exists:here/undergraduate-study/highlghts-grad"
tal:replace="structure here/undergraduate-study/highlghts-grad/getText">Footer content here</tal:block>
</p>
</div>
```

etc, etc for all tabs...

Comment: What is the question - reading the posting three times still does not give me any insight what your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

The global tabs in Plone are navigation roots. You can detect the *current active* navigation root in two ways:

- The body HTML tag has a `section-[id_of_section]` CSS class, where `id_of_section` varies with the pathname of each section.

  From a viewlet or portlet you can retrieve these classes using the `@@plone_layout` view:

  ```
  tal:define="plone_layout context/@@plone_layout;
              bodyClass python:plone_layout.bodyClass(template, view)"
  ```

  after which you'll have to test if a certain `state-` string is present in the bodyClass value.
- By retrieving he current navigation root directly from the `@@plone_portal_state` view:

  ```
  tal:define="plone_portal_state context/@@plone_portal_state;
              nav_root plone_portal_state/navigation_root;
              nav_root_id nav_root/getId"
  ```

  You can then vary your viewlet or portlet based on the `nav_root_id`.

Note however that each navigation root is has a portal type, and possibly an interface declaration, that you could use to register viewlets or portlets for. Detecting the exact navigation is usually not the best option.

Comment: See also http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functionality/actions.html#tabs-sections

Comment: If it helps here is an image of what I am trying to achieve: [link](http://static.inky.ws/image/2602/image.jpg)

Comment: @emb03: Use JavaScript and CSS selectors then; the body tag has  a `section-` class.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is commonly referred to as a "megamenu."  There is a product that implements this for Plone, http://plone.org/products/collective.collage.megamenu/.  I've not used it, but I'd certainly recommend that you explore it as a starting point.

Comment: I tried that but I got errors installing it through buildout so I couldn't add it.